# Draw lines on zoom image

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, drawing, pinchzoom

I have taken one `imageview` in `scrollview` with max zoom 4. I want to draw a line on that image.

Currently I am using `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` methods. But to use those methods, I have to make user interaction false for `scrollView` therefore I can not zoom `scrollview`. In short, I can use only one feature at a time either zoom or draw on an image.

Is there any way to do it simultaneously?

Comment: You may give the buttons to user where user can change the mode either drawing or scrolling and zooming. Because you never know that what is user intention he wants to draw or he wants to move the zoomed image

Comment: Thanks @PrashantTukadiya. I have already done this scenario but I have read somewhere that we can do it by checking whether gesture requires multitouch or single touch. I did so many research on that but can't get any links to that logic.

Comment: No, you can do it simultaneously. As @PrashantTukadiya said, you can not guess user intention either user want to draw a line or scroll at given point of time.

Comment: You can do like when you detect 2 finger then move /zoom image and if you detect one finger then draw lines on images.

Comment: @Mahendra Excellent !! , Bansi You can do that. you can detect two fingers to choose between draw or zoom

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya thank you for your valuable suggestion. I have made custom class of uiImageView for drawing purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scrollview delegate if the zoom event for the scrollview is started or completedas below :

```
    func scrollViewWillBeginZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?) {
            //When zoom with pinch gesture started
          needToDraw = false
    }

    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            //When zoom with pinch gesture ended
          needToDraw = true
    }
```

You can manage a boolean value to detect if the user is zooming or not. needToDraw variable does that here.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks @BhargavR but this was partial solution for me but also needed one.